# No Lubuntu 14.04LTS Unetbootin?

Tags: unetbootin

I have use synaptic package manager to download unetbootin but no live version of Lubuntu 14.04 LTS is listed? Or is it me?

Comment: it seems there I have Ubuntu 14.04 , https://i.imgur.com/cJj2O1t.png

Answer (score 2):

[image: UNetbootin Launch Screen]

UNetbootin will use pretty much any .ISO you throw at it. Download Lubuntu 14.04 LTS and point UNetbootin at it.

1. Download Lubuntu 14.04 from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu).

   See picture above to continue these instructions.
2. Click  the  DiskImage radio button at lower left of the UNetbootin screen.
3. Choose the ISO option on the right next to the radio button you just selected near the bottom center of the UNetbootin screen.
4. Browse to your Download directory using the ... button and choose the file you just downloaded.

You can use this approach for any ISO distribution that you can't find on the list.

Comment: When I open unetbootin distributions I don't get the Lubuntu option

Comment: @Frenchman Please follow the simple steps in the answer above which I have edited to improve clarity. If this works for you Please upvote and accept the answer so that it can help others as well.

Comment: @Frenchman did this work for you?